# OleDbDataReader gives Unsupported Data Type Error

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I am using Oracle Db and calling a Simple Select Query but Oracle is throwing a weird error message:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Unspecified error Oracle error occurred,
>   but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle. Data type is not
>   supported.

[This is CDB Class](http://pastie.org/7807412)

This is How I am calling:

```
        CDb conn = new CDb();
        conn.getConnection();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        String query = "Select * FROM Table";
        reader = conn.find(query);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Going...");
        }
```

On debugging it thorws exception after printing above mentioned error message. What I am doing wrong?

Database schema:

```sql
SB_ID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
SB_TITLE                                           VARCHAR2(200)
SB_ONDATE                                          TIMESTAMP(0)
SB_RCVDDATE_QAMRI                                  VARCHAR2(10)
SB_RCVDDATE_SHAMSI                                 DATE
SB_MODE                                            NUMBER(1)
SB_PREFERENCE                                      NUMBER(1)
SB_STATUS                                          NUMBER(1)
SB_RASEED_ISSUED                                   NUMBER(1)
SB_MUJIB_ID                                        NUMBER(11)
SB_RECVD_BY_ID                                     NUMBER(11)
SB_MUSTAFTI_FULLNAME                               VARCHAR2(100)
SB_MUSTAFTI_ADDRESS                                VARCHAR2(100)
SB_MUSTAFTI_COUNTRY                                NUMBER(3)
SB_MUSTAFTI_CITY                                   VARCHAR2(100)
SB_MUSTAFTI_STATE                                  VARCHAR2(100)
SB_MUSTAFTI_MOBILE                                 VARCHAR2(20)
SB_MUSTAFTI_PHONE                                  VARCHAR2(20)
SB_MUSTAFTI_FAX                                    VARCHAR2(20)
SB_MUSTAFTI_EMAIL                                  VARCHAR2(40)
SB_MUSTAFTI_NIC                                    VARCHAR2(20)
SB_DISTRIBUTION_DATE                               DATE
SB_ISSUEDATE_QAMRI                                 VARCHAR2(10)
SB_ISSUEDATE_SHAMSI                                DATE
```

Comment: You should show the schema of the table you are trying to read.

Comment: [i guess you have a clob column in the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537613/how-to-read-a-clob-column-in-oracle-using-oledb)

Comment: @Steve Schema is attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potentially troublesome datatype in the posted schema is a TIMESTAMP but according to the docs that is supported by OLE DB 10g.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10115/using.htm).

So, either you're not using a modern version of OLE DB, or there is a more obscure problem with your table.  A tiresome but foolproof way of debugging this would be to specify some column names in the query and find which one it doesn't like.

Comment: issue is that particular Query/Routine, the other Select Query in different method working just fine. OleDbDataReader returns null.

Comment: APC you were right! Mentioning COlumn Names instead of asterik worked. Weird. What could be the issue?